# Rendering transparency in one compositing node only

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am brand new to compositing nodes, and I am trying to figure out how to render out one layer with transparency, and the other without.

For example, My background, I don't want transparent to be the option, but for my character, I do want the background to be transparent.

Is there a way I can do this?

Also, is there a way to effect how much the light works on one pass as opposed to the other?

I want the lights to effect the character pass at about 50% of how the would effect the background pass...

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if you have any recommendations.